# Using MySql Document Store in Quarkus give exception "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/protobuf/Message" while creating session

Tags: mysql-x-devapi

I am trying to use MySql Document Store in Quarkus. Following is the code for creating a session and reading the collection

```
public class MyService {
    @Inject
    DataSource dataSource;

    @ConfigProperty(name = "datasource.url")
    private String url;

    public void executeDevApiService() throws SQLException {
        Session session = new SessionFactory().getSession(url);
        Schema schema = session.getSchema("workflows");
        Collection coll = schema.getCollection("order");
        DocResult result = coll.find().execute();
        while(result.hasNext()) {
            DbDoc row = result.fetchOne();
            System.out.println(row.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

This is my application.properties configuration

```
datasource.url=mysqlx://localhost:33060/workflows?user=root&password=root
```

While execution following exception is received.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/protobuf/Message
        at com.mysql.cj.MysqlxSession.<init>(MysqlxSession.java:61)
        at com.comviva.pacs.MyService.executeDevApiService(MyService.java:33)
        at com.comviva.pacs.MyService_ClientProxy.executeDevApiService(Unknown Source)
        at com.comviva.pacs.Resource.findAll(Resource.java:48)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:154)
```

Following is pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.comviva.pacs</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysqldocument</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.11.0</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>3.1.1.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
    <skipITs>true</skipITs>
    <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0</surefire-plugin.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-mysql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jsonb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jsonb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>all</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.15.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
      <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
      <version>3.23.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
              <goal>generate-code</goal>
              <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-parameters</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
            <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <systemPropertyVariables>
                <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
              </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>native</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>native</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <skipITs>false</skipITs>
        <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Tried to use mysql XdevApi to fetch the collection from MySql Document Store using Quarkus.